# Idiomatic `obj.value = f(obj)` in Ramda?

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

`R.evolve` lets us replace object properties with the result of a function applied to that property's current value:

```
R.evolve({ count: R.inc }, { count: 1 })
   == { count: 2 }
```

But I frequently find I want to add a property calculated from multiple properties of input object:

```
assocFruitTotal({ appleCount: 5, orangeCount: 3 })
  == { appleCount: 5, orangeCount: 3, fruitCount: 8 }
```

I came up with my own simple utility function:

```
const assocDerived = R.curry(
   (name, f, obj) => ({
      ...obj,
      [name]: f(obj)
   });
```

... and I use it a lot:

```
const sumFruit = R.pipe(
   R.props(['appleCount', 'orangeCount']),
   R.sum);
const assocFruitTotal = assocDerived('fruitCount', sumFruit);
```

But the sheer frequency with which I use this makes me wonder why it's not
native to Ramda, as so many other convenient functions are. And that makes
me wonder whether I'm missing a better idiom that achieves the outcome -- that is, building up detail in an object by adding properties based upon combinations of other properties.

Is there an idiomatic functional programming construct I should be using instead?

Comment: The more general functional idiom are comonads, which are for unpacking values along with their contexts.

Comment: A PR making this suggestion would be welcomed by the Ramda team.  It might make sense to either expand `evolve` or add a new function like this.  No guarantees it would be accepted, but it would get a fair hearing.

Comment: `applySpec` does exactly `o[prop] = f(o)`, just bear in mind that the returned `f` might need to be forced to be `unary`.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would do it this way:

```js
const fruitCount = applySpec({fruitCount: compose(sum, values)})

fruitCount({apple: 5, orange: 3})
//=> {"fruitCount": 8}

const withFruitCount = converge(mergeRight, [identity, fruitCount]);

withFruitCount({apple: 5, orange: 3});
//=> {"apple": 5, "fruitCount": 8, "orange": 3}
```

If there are non-count properties to exclude from the sum, you can use `pickBy`:

```js
const pickCount = pickBy(flip(includes('Count')));

pickCount({appleCount: 5, orangeCount: 3, foo: 'bar'});
//=> {"appleCount": 5, "orangeCount": 3}
```

Comment: I guess the question is whether that idiom is common enough that a reader would always grok it straight away. I can also write my `assocDerived` something like `assocDerived =(name, fn) => converge(mergeRight, [ identity,  applySpec({[name]: fn})])` of course.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by recognizing that `obj.value = f(obj)` is a mutable assignment and therefore not a functional idiom to begin with. This is imperative-style thinking at work.

Storing a computed value as a property on your object is a misstep, in most cases. If either `appleCount` or `orangeCount` changes, there's nothing there to enforce the integrity of `fruitCount`.

`fruitCount` should be a *function*, not a property.

```
const fruitCount =
  pipe
    ( props ([ 'appleCount', 'orangeCount' ])
    , sum
    )

 fruitCount ({ appleCount: 1, orangeCount: 3 }) // 4
 fruitCount ({ appleCount: 5, orangeCount: 3 }) // 8
```

If I had to guess, this is fake data and an example problem. In some scenarios, a computed value does make sense (memoisation is the first technique that comes to mind) but those cases make up the exception, not the rule. You say *"the sheer frequency with which I use this ..."*, so I'd wager you do it in more areas than you should.

And as you pointed out, Ramda doesn't have a built-in for this, so this should further indicate that there are more conventional ways of solving this kind of problem.

---

An object-oriented programmer would assign this as a computed property -

```js
const FruitData = function (apples = 0, oranges = 0)
{ this.apples = apples
  this.oranges = oranges
}

Object.defineProperty
  ( FruitData.prototype
  , 'fruitCount'
  , { get () { return this.apples + this.oranges } }
  )
  
const f =
  new FruitData (3, 4)
  
console .log (f.fruitCount) // 7
```

When writing functional style, we leave OOP concepts at the door. Start thinking in terms of functions and your problems go away -

```js
const FruitData = (apples = 0, oranges = 0) =>
  ({ apples, oranges })

const appleCount = fd =>
  fd.apples

const orangeCount = fd =>
  fd.oranges

const fruitCount = fd =>
  appleCount (fd) + orangeCount (fd)

console .log (fruitCount (FruitData (10, 3))) // 13
```

Comment: While I was a little imprecise in the title of the question, for conciseness, I think it's clear from the body of the question that I didn't want to mutate an object. My `assocDerived`, like `R.assoc` and `R.evolve` returns a new clone of the input with the requested prop replaced. Your fruitcount is obvious enough stuff, but no use when further down the composition of calls, you still need the other parts of the input. `pipe( assocDerived('fruitCount', sumFruit), o => 'You have ${o.oranges} oranges, ${o.apples} apples for a total of ${fruitCount} fruit')`

Comment: Your point-free obsession is [hurting you](https://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html). `(fd => \`You have ${orangeCount(fd)} oranges, ${appleCount(fd)} apples for a total of ${fruitCount(fd)}\`)` is a perfectly good function.